# How to fix this XSS in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, security, escaping, xss

I don't know if it counts as a XSS, but it is causing errors

I have an image_tag and  the `:alt` tag is generated by the user

however, using `sanitize`/`h`/`html_escape` doesn't help with this (from OWASP- [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet#XSS_Locator))

```
';alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//';alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//";
alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//";alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//--
></SCRIPT>">'><SCRIPT>alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))</SCRIPT>
```

when doing

```
:alt => (the string above)
```

the output of the image is messed up

Is there a way to fix this XSS?

I'm using latest rails,ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Rails 3.2.8 and thus the fix of [CVE-2012-3464](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rubyonrails-security/kKGNeMrnmiY/r2yM7xy-G48J), the Rails escape helpers escape both double quotes and single quotes.

If you are actually using the correct version, you should be just fine.

```
>> ERB::Util.h '\';alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//\';alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//";alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//";alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//--></SCRIPT>">\'><SCRIPT>alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))</SCRIPT>'
=> "&#39;;alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//&#39;;alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//&quot;;alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//&quot;;alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//--&gt;&lt;/SCRIPT&gt;&quot;&gt;&#39;&gt;&lt;SCRIPT&gt;alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))&lt;/SCRIPT&gt;"
```

(Note: the backslashes in the above raw string need to be there for Ruby to properly parse the string which then contains the single quotes verbatim.)

Answer (score 0):

u can fix it by filter " ' and >   just this three characters is ennough